How to manage custom size and size variant selections in Shopify
I’m working at a Shopify store where I have both size variants and a custom size input for products. I need to implement logic so that:

If a user selects a size variant, the custom size input should not be included in the cart.
Conversely, if the user inputs a custom size, the selected size variant should be excluded from the cart.

This is a part of my liquid code:
<div class="select">
      <select id="product-select-{{ product.id }}{{ product-form }}{{ section.id }}{{ block.id }}" name="id" class="multi_select" data-variants>
        {% for v in product.variants %}
          <option {% if v == variant %}selected="selected"{% endif %} value="{{ v.id }}" data-featured-image="{{ v.featured_media }}" data-image="{{ v.featured_media | product_img_url: '600x' }}" data-sku="{{ v.sku }}">{{ v.title }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
      </select>
      {% if product.tags contains 'Custom Size' %}
        <div>
          <!-- Add this button to toggle custom size fields -->
          <div class='toggle-customizable-wrapper'>
            Or
            <button type="button" id="toggle-custom-size">Custom Size</button>
          </div>
          <!-- Custom size fields -->
          <div id="custom-size-fields" style="display:none; margin-top: 10px;">    
            <label for="unit-of-measure">Unit of Measure:</label>
            <select id="unit-of-measure" class="custom-size-input" name="properties[Unit of Measure]">
              <option value="cm">Cm</option>
              <option value="ft">Ft</option>
            </select>
            <p>
              Selected size: <span class="chosen-size">0 x 0</span> <span class="chosen-unit">Cm</span>
            </p>
            <div class='product-custom-size-container'>
              <div>
                <label for="custom-width">Width:</label>
                <input type="number" value='0' id="custom-width" class="custom-size-input" name="properties[Custom Width]" min="1"  placeholder="Enter width">
              </div>
              <div>
                <label for="custom-length">Length:</label>
                <input type="number" value='0' id="custom-length" class="custom-size-input" name="properties[Custom Length]" min="1"  placeholder="Enter length">
              </div>
              <div class="chosen-unit-container">
                <p class="chosen-unit">Cm</p>        
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

and this is the script code:
<script>
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    const widthSize = document.getElementById('custom-width');
    const lengthSize = document.getElementById('custom-length');
    const selectorOptionSize = document.querySelector('[data-option="option3"]'); // the size variant must be the third one in variants list
    let isSizeCustomable = false;
    
    const productDetailsForm = document.getElementById('product_form_{{ product.id }}');
    productDetailsForm.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();  // Prevent the default form submission
      event.stopImmediatePropagation();
      console.log('Form submission intercepted');  // Check if this logs
    });

    // code for handling the changes of custom size
  
    //code for handling the change of unit
  
    //code for toggle the custom size block
  });

I have tried to intercept the form after submission, but this does not work.
